# Difficulty give me full name back - the return is not content

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, view

This is how I try return full name back but it gives me just this

up in the main I angularjs 1.5.x file, it is from their CDN I get their code from.

Problem is that when I write eg first name and last name into the shows just this thick and I have nothing written so it also shows what I have written below.

```
 {{fullName()}}
```

I have also tried to tag **()** away and add them again and still show it as I have written about here.

Create.cshtml file:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" ng-app="UserValue" ng-controller="UserFirstValue">

    @using (Html.BeginForm(HelperSettingsClass.HelperSettings.AccountCreate, HelperSettingsClass.HelperSettings.AccountMappe, FormMethod.Post, new
    {
        @class = "form-horizontal"
    }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Fornavn)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Fornavn, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @id = "Firstname",
               @ng_model = "FirstnameApp",
               @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Fornavn,
               @required = ""
           })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Fornavn, "", new
           {
               @class = "label label-danger"
           })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Efternavn)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Efternavn, new
           {
               @class = "form-control",
               @id = "Lastname",
               @ng_model = "LastnameApp",
               @placeholder = HelperTextClass.HelperText.placeholderInfo.Efternavn,
               @required = ""
           })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Efternavn, "", new
           {
               @class = "label label-danger"
           })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <p class="label label-danger"></p>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="clickUserCreate"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> {{fullName()}}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

User.js - Angularjs file:

```
var app = angular.module('UserValue', []);
app.controller('UserFirstValue', function ($scope) {
    if ($scope.FirstnameApp != null && $scope.LastnameApp != null)
    {
        $scope.fullName = function () {
            return "Velkommen" + $scope.FirstnameApp + " " + $scope.LastnameApp;
        };
    }
    else
    {
        $scope.fullName = function () {
            return "Opret bruger";
        };
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic of your controller is only run on initialization, so the functions will not be created, because those variables will not have values yet.

So instead, do something like this:

```
$scope.fullName = function () {
    if ($scope.FirstnameApp != null && $scope.LastnameApp != null)
        return "Velkommen" + $scope.FirstnameApp + " " + $scope.LastnameApp;
    else
        return "Opret bruger";
};
```

Note:

I actually think it kind of ugly to use a function for this. It violates general AngularJS style guidelines, because you are putting view concerns in your controller. It would be nicer to do something like this:

```
<div ng-show="firstName && lastName">
    Welcome, {{name}} {{lastName}}
</div>
<div ng-hide="firstName && lastName">
    No name
</div>
```

Comment: It does not help the still make it together. :(

Comment: its make error from AngularJs file, You can see here: http://postimg.org/image/jpcy0mgr1/

Comment: Angular error messages are great. They are displayed as stacktraces and contain clickable links to the docs with a detailed description of the problem. Use it.

Comment: its show me: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ng/areq?p0=UserFirstValue&p1=not%20a%20function,%20got%20undefined

Comment: Edit that error into your question, not as a png, and replace the html template with the actual html that is generated from that.

Comment: What you mean on its?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You are calling a function that is not defined. But I don't think you do that in any of the code you posted.

Comment: Wvdz i find "ng-app" toppe of my layout.cshtml And now its work for me! Thanks for help!!!

Comment: and i hope u will giv me +1 for its ask, ;)